# Getting an error while building a register page, AttributeError at /register/ 'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: python, django

I am building a registration page using Python 2.7.15 && Django 1.11.18, but continue to get the error:

```
AttributeError at /register/
'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

I've looked through other very similar posts, tried the suggestions, but still I am not getting a functional result. To me it looks like everything is in order, but it is not. Below you will find my code, thanks.

Views.py looks like:

```
def register_page(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        username  = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    print(new_user)

    return render(request, "auth/register.html", context)
```

forms.py looks like:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField()
email    = forms.EmailField()
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
    if password2 != password:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match.")
    return data
```

urls.py looks like:

```
   from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import home_page, about_page, contact_page, login_page, register_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_page), 
    url(r'^about/$', about_page),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact_page),
    url(r'^login/$', login_page),
    url(r'^register/$', register_page),                  
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

## below is the traceback

```
   Request Method:  GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/register/
Django Version: 1.11.18
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
Exception Location: /Users/isaacr./Desktop/Ecommerce_Python/ecommerce/src/ecommerce/views.py in register_page, line 110
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.15
Python Path:    
['/Users/isaacr./Desktop/Ecommerce_Python/ecommerce/src',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.15.1/libexec/nose/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 11 Jan 2019 19:44:01 +0000
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show the traceback. Where exactly is this error happening?

Comment: It says that line 110 is the issue: email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")

Answer (score -1):

in forms.py you say:

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
....
```

But `self.cleaned_data` *is* undefined - at no point does your example include a line like `self.cleaned_data = <something>`

So the line `data = self.cleaned_data` complains that it doesn't know what `self.cleaned_data` is.

Comment: Ok makes sense, but what should i put in between <>?

Comment: That depends, but perhaps `super().clean()` ?